# Enable http compression using Ace editor and Xtext Web?

Tags: xtext

We are using Xtext Web 2.9.2 with the Ace editor and would like to be able to enable compression for all made from Ace to/from Xtext (update, assist, validate, etc).

For example:
* be able to compress the content assist result that Xtext sends back to the client.
* client "update" editor requests sent to Xtext are compressed.

Is there a way to make Ace and Xtext use compression this way?

Comment: isnt this a thing that is agnostic to the client and server part of xtext but rather a setting in the servlet part of xtext?

Comment: Ah, you're suggesting to look at the MyDslServlet that extends XtextServlet? It looks like the request and response can be accessed and encoding handled there. Thanks for the tip/hint, I think that may be what I was looking for - will give it a try.